# Independence - Increments of fractional Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am interested in fractional Brownian motion recently.

But I have a question about its Long range dependence(LRD)

---

$\text{For fractional Brownian motion}$ $B(t), X(t)=B(n+1)-B(n)$ $\text{, n is integer, has long range dependence.  }$

$\text{it means its auto-correlation }$ $ \lim_{|i-j|\to\infty}\rho_{i,j} = 0 $

$\text{In this case, we can say }$ $X(i)$ $\text{ and }$ $X(j)$ $\text{ are uncorrelated when }$ $|i-j|\to\infty$

$But \text{ could we say } $$X(i)$ $\text{ and }$ $X(j)$ $\text{are nearly independent in this limit case?}$

---

I think we couldn't because correlation is different from independence.

Please give me a little help.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer!

We can say they are nearly independent in this limit case, due to its normality.

$X(t)$$\text{ follows Gaussian distribution because it is from fBm}$

$\text{For Gaussian distributions, zero covariance implies independence.}$

Comment: I hoped for the same conclusion, but this reasoning proves the opposite https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent